# How to make a rich textbox automatically size in wpf?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls, richtextbox

How to make a RichTextBox automatically size? I want my rich textbox to fit with any text I assign to it without having scroll bars. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` to something other than `Stretch` (which is the default). This will make the TextBox shrink to fit its contents. If you then stick it inside a `StackPanel` with `Orientation` of `Horizontal` it will not scroll vertically but be clipped by its containing panel, which I think is what you are after. If you want you containing panel to resize itself to the text, then you need to configure the panel accordingly

Comment: big thanks Dean Chalk, that was useful but still having one problem,my richTextBox take the width of any thing which put it on ..like stack Panel width , but I want to make it's width to fit just his content. plz help me . thanks advanced

Comment: Unfortunately, RichTextBox stretches horizontally even when HorizontalAlignment is set to left/right/center. Probably something to do with it holding a FlowDocument.

Answer (score 1):

```
        Bitmap objBmpImage = new Bitmap(1, 1);

        int intWidth = 0;
        int intHeight = 0;

        // Create the Font object for the image text drawing.
        Font objFont = new Font("Arial", 20, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        // Create a graphics object to measure the text's width and height.
        Graphics objGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(objBmpImage);

        // This is where the bitmap size is determined.
        intWidth = (int)objGraphics.MeasureString(sImageText, objFont).Width;
        intHeight = (int)objGraphics.MeasureString(sImageText, objFont).Height;
```

You already have string to set textbox. Firstly, you can calculate like above to measure proper size of richtextbox. you can just set intWidth and intHeight at textbox.
I think that makes you helpful.

Comment: that seems good, but I want to make it resize itself automatically when size of stack panel which contain my RichTextBox changed.
I get it by Set the HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment to something other than Stretch (which is the default).like Dean Chalk answered me . but i still having another problem, I'll say it in Dean Chalk comment aria. :) thanx DiainWate :)

Answer (score -1):

Try using the ViewBox

```
<Viewbox>
    <RichTextBox />
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. Your XAML will scale the TextBox to fit the container (And will scale the text too). The question is "how do you ensure that the RichTextBox becomes bigger when the text Inside become longer."