# WPF Size RichTextBox according to contents

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="myContinuousTemplate">
                  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MaxWidth="300"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <messenger:BindableRichTextBox Grid.Column="1" 
                             MaxWidth="300"
                             Style="{StaticResource richTextBoxStyle}" TextChanged="BindableRichTextBox_TextChanged">
                    <messenger:BindableRichTextBox.Document>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource searchTextHighlightConverter}">
                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Mode="OneTime"/>
                            <Binding Path="message" />
                            <Binding Path="message_sn" />
                            <Binding Mode="TwoWay" ElementName="conversationControl" Path="SearchText" />
                            <Binding Mode="TwoWay" ElementName="conversationControl" Path="MatchedMessageSN" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </messenger:BindableRichTextBox.Document>
                </messenger:BindableRichTextBox>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Message is being implemented. 
I want to get the richtextbox property of the data template.

The final goal is to change the length of the richbox by the characters you enter.

For example, like Facebook Messenger, I want to stretch to the length of the letter, but when it reaches the maximum length I want to stretch it vertically.

Comment: "enter image description here"  is example..

Comment: You can find answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347518/how-to-make-a-rich-textbox-automatically-size-in-wpf

Comment: @P10trek  I already tried it, but it failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment to something other than Stretch (which is the default). This will make the TextBox shrink to fit its contents. hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Try put your richtexbox's in stackpanel i try following code and it working exacly as u want:

```
     <StackPanel>
        <RichTextBox/>
        <RichTextBox/>
        <RichTextBox/>
        <RichTextBox/>
        <RichTextBox/>
        <RichTextBox/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Behaviour that you want to obtain is standard behaviuor. Check style of your richtextbox propably there is some bug.